# Closest datetime match within a group for multiple items with multiple entries

Tags: sql, datetime, join, group-by, subquery

```
Grp-01  Item001 18/03/2021 05:12    10  5
Grp-01  Item001 18/03/2021 05:19    9   8
Grp-01  Item001 18/03/2021 06:14    8   2
Grp-01  Item001 18/03/2021 06:15    10  3
Grp-01  Item001 18/03/2021 06:16    2   1
Grp-01  Item001 18/03/2021 06:20    3   2
Grp-01  Item002 18/03/2021 04:12    10  5
Grp-01  Item002 18/03/2021 04:20    9   8
Grp-01  Item002 18/03/2021 04:34    8   2
Grp-01  Item002 18/03/2021 04:44    10  3
Grp-01  Item002 18/03/2021 05:20    2   1
Grp-01  Item002 18/03/2021 06:21    3   2
Grp-01  Item003 18/03/2021 04:12    10  5
Grp-01  Item003 18/03/2021 06:04    9   8
Grp-01  Item003 18/03/2021 05:14    8   2
Grp-01  Item003 18/03/2021 06:11    10  3
Grp-01  Item003 18/03/2021 06:19    2   1
Grp-01  Item003 18/03/2021 06:21    3   2
Grp-01  Item004 18/03/2021 03:12    10  5
Grp-01  Item004 18/03/2021 03:34    9   8
Grp-01  Item004 18/03/2021 04:11    8   2
Grp-01  Item004 18/03/2021 05:19    10  3
Grp-01  Item004 18/03/2021 06:01    2   1
Grp-01  Item004 18/03/2021 06:29    3   2
```

From the above table desired output now:

```
ProductGroup    Item    DateTime    Value   Qty
Grp-01  Item001 18/03/2021 05:19    9   8
Grp-01  Item002 18/03/2021 05:20    2   1
Grp-01  Item003 18/03/2021 05:14    8   2
Grp-01  Item004 18/03/2021 05:19    10  3
```

I have a dataset with a group and a group contains 4 set of items (Item001, Item002, Item003 & Item004). Item001 is repeated six times with a different date and same for the other items in the group. Now, I need to find the closest datetime for each item set in a group as shown in the desired output. Please note for each item I will have one row by group and by datetime as shown in the desired output above.

The closest date query matches one item set i.e. Item001 with each other item sets.

Can anyone please guide me how to achieve the desired results using SQL query?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Closest date time to what?

Answer (score 0):

This seems really tricky.  In SQL you would have to compare all datetimes for each item and then choose the set that is "minimal" by your definition:

```
select t1.*, t2.*, t3.*, t4.*
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.productgroup = t2.productgroup join
     t t3
     on t1.productgroup = t3.productgroup join
     t t4
     on t1.productgroup = t4.productgroup
where t1.item = 'Item001' and
      t2.item = 'Item002' and
      t3.item = 'Item003' and
      t4.item = 'Item004' 
order by abs(t2.datetime - t1.datetime) +
         abs(t3.datetime - t1.datetime) +
         abs(t4.datetime - t1.datetime) +
         abs(t3.datetime - t2.datetime) +
         abs(t4.datetime - t2.datetime) +
         abs(t4.datetime - t3.datetime)
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note that date/time functions vary by database so you would probably need to adjust the syntax for your database.

And, this puts the values in columns rather than as separate rows.

Also, this answers the question that you have asked here.  It does not generalize very well.  If you have a different question, then you might want to ask it as a new question.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting an error when I run this command in sql server, The error is "Invalid usage of the option first in the FETCH statement". This command is not running in SQL server, can you give me an SQL server equivalent please?

Comment: @DataNuker . . . As the answer explains, you have to adapt the syntax for whatever database you are using.  Your question does not have a database tag.